# Unable to replace an existing column basis on another column

Tags: python, regex

Below are two dataframes. The dataframe df1 is a cleanfile which has to be used as the mapping file to another dataframe df2 which has uncleaned information.

```py
    df1=pd.DataFrame({'Make': {0: 'ASHOK LEYLAND', 1: 'ASTON MARTIN', 2: 'ASTON MARTIN'},
     'Model': {0: 'STILE', 1: 'DB9', 2: 'RAPIDE'},
     'Variant': {0: 'LE 7 STR', 1: 'VOLANTE', 2: 'LUXE'},
     'Fuel': {0: 'DIESEL', 1: 'PETROL', 2: 'PETROL'}})

    df2=pd.DataFrame({'Make': {0: 'ASHOK LEYLANDSTILELE 7 STR',
      1: 'ASTON MARTINDB9VOLANTE',
      2: 'ASTON MARTINRAPIDELUXE'},
     'Model': {0: 'STILELE 7 STR', 1: 'DB9VOLANTE', 2: 'RAPIDELUXE'},
     'Variant': {0: 'LE 7 STRSTILE', 1: 'VOLANTEDB9', 2: 'LUXERAPIDE'},
     'Fuel': {0: 'Dieseel', 1: 'Dieseel', 2: 'PETROLjlljlj'}})
```

I have used the below code to clean the 'Make' column of df2 basis on the 'Make' column of df1. However i dont get any result on my new column 'Make_new'.Below is the code:

```py
    df2['Make_new'] = df2['Make'].apply(lambda v: [Make for Make in df1 if Make in ('ASHOK','ASTON')])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match a given set of "allowed" names to the the defective values and extract only the matched part. Note that following solution will only cover the situation in which the defective names have correct prefixes.

```
import re

def clean_col(correct_names_expression):
    def clean_row_func(x):
        if match_res := re.match(correct_names_expression, x):  # if no match is asserted, then None is returned
            return match_res[0]
        else:
            return None
    return clean_row_func

func_to_correct_rows = clean_col('(' + '|'.join(df1.Make.tolist()) + ')')

df2.Make.apply(func_to_correct_rows )

Out:
0    ASHOK LEYLAND
1     ASTON MARTIN
2     ASTON MARTIN
```

Comment: The code works fine with the set of data i provided. However when I pass the code to my actual data which has a shape of (840638, 4), then it is throwing an error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".

Comment: @yocodefreak I modified the code. Have a look and try. The problem was that when no match occurs a None is returned (which is not subscriptable).

Comment: Thanks for the code. however when I removed the space 'ASHOKLEYLANDSTILELE 7 STR' then the output is 'None'. Can you please help?

Comment: @yocodefreak note that this novel situation you just describe is not part of your question. It seems you have a huge dataset with many potential situations, meaning this back and forth will keep going. You need to figure out what kind of irregularities in d2 are "acceptable" and devise a strategy to translate it into the "correct" one. As per this answer, any string starting with any known value of df1.Make will be "accepted" and the string starting returned. For more into this type of pattern matching, have a look at [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would need `df1` at all. The "cleaning" logic is pretty simple. This will do the trick.

```
def clean(row):
    if 'ASHOK' in row.Make:
        return 'ASHOK LEYLAND'
    if 'ASTON' in row.Make:
        return 'ASTON MARTIN'
    return row.Make

df2['cleaned'] = df2.apply(clean, axis=1)
```

Comment: This logic won't be self maintainable. If a new make comes in, the OP will have to update the amount of if conditions.

Comment: That is easily solvable by keeping a dictionary mapping the keywords. The OP wasn't specific enough. I would be happy to generalize the code if the OP provides example DataFrames.